# missing DLL file when i run my application on another machine?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependencies, installshield, missing-data

I am using visual studio 2013 with ISLE 2013 to create a windows form application,
it is the first time i use this style,

I successfully built the application but the problem comes after i setup the application on another PC is says msvcp120.dll is missing!

I have searched the web for this problem and I could not find anything?

any ideas?

Comment: You need to install the redistributable for visual studio 2013. I do not have VS2013 yet however on Visual Studio Pro 2012 the redistributables are in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\redist\1033

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2013 ultimate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution I should add the Visual C++ runtime library installer

Answer (score 2):

I am not a windows guy but I will try to answer, as I did some small research. I found information [here](http://systemexplorer.net/file-database/file/msvcp120-dll). It says:

"This file is the dynamic linking library designed as a Microsoft C Runtime Library, usually comming with Microsoft® Visual Studio®. It is a collection of link libraries that contains instructions for the standard C library functions. It is used by almost all Windows programs compiled from C or C++ source code. This library is used for the applications written under Visual Studio."

So, I am guessing it is a microsoft thing. A runtime library that is required to run c/c++ projects built with visual studios. Download the .dll from a source online (just google) and include it into your project directory. If it helps, include that file in your installation file.

Until anybody who is working with windows and has any idea about that dll answers you question, this answer can help you to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Don't download single DLL's from which you know hardly anything from random sites.
From your Visual Studio 2013 installation directory, check C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist\1033 and you'll see vcredist_x64.exe and vcredist_x86.exe files that need to be run on your target system.
Use the x64 variant for 64 bit apps. It will install MSVCP120.dll for one, and some other DLL's as well.

Answer (score 1):

Msvcp120.dll is the dll for standard c++ library. When you develop an application using standard c++ in VS 2013, the application defaults to Msvcp120.dll(Msvcp110.dll in VS2012). The client computer should install Visual c++ 2013 Redistributable.

Answer (score 0):

Some dependencies that are on your system because you have Visual Studio installed will not be on the target system. You will need to include them in your installer or install a redistributable package on the target machine.

As there are many options and listing them all here would be too much and also redundant, you may want to visit the [Microsoft site for this task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kche8ah.aspx) and read up on all those options before you decide which you chose.

Comment: I know why the dependency is caused, i can't resolve it for installation project

Answer (score -4):

You can download the `.dll` file from [DLL Store](http://www.dll-files.com) and paste that file into the `directory` where you have installed the setup.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This would be a hack. It would be more appropriate to install the dll from his installer or XCopy deployment or install a redistributable from Microsoft instead of getting executable code from a shady internet source.

Comment: 'shady internet source' is the reason for my downvote.